# How do I find a string within a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
import mod
import csv

website = 'stackoverflow'

mod.write_browserhistory_txt()

def check():
    with open('chrome_history.csv', 'rt') as csv_file:
        csv_read = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_read:
            if website in row: 
                print (row, "available")
            else:
                print ("not available")
    return 

check()
```

I wrote this code for one of my projects and to make this project work I need to check if a string is available in a csv file.
With this code, the value of `website` must be the same as the one in the csv file, only then it will show as available. However I want to search up a word from the csv file.

For example in my csv file I have:

```
stackoverflow.com
github.com
youtube.com
```

when the value of `website` is `stackoverflow`, I get the output `not available`

but when the value of `website` is `stackoverflow.com`, I get the output `available`

I am new in python so can someone help me with this?

Comment: The hacky way to do this would be to use String.split(). The correct way to do it is to use Regular Expressions. Check out the re module in Python.

Comment: Is this occurring due to the fact that you are trying to see if `stackoverflow` is equal to `stackoverflow.com`? If so, you could just check if the value of `website` exists in the string `row` (using some help from a try/catch and `string.index()`)

Answer (score 0):

try this code it may help you

```
import mod
import csv

website = 'stackoverflow'

mod.write_browserhistory_txt()

def check():
    with open('chrome_history.csv', 'rt') as csv_file:
        csv_read = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_read:
            try:
                row.index(website)
                print(row, "available")
            except:
                print ("not available")
    return 

check()
```

use index method to find sub-string

Comment: I am not familiar with index method can you help me out?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_index.asp

Comment: even though my history is from pages of this website, I get the output

`not available
not available
not available
not available
not available
not available
not available
not available
not available
not available`

Comment: check that row contain each line of your csv file